# kdb string path miss quotation mark

Tags: kdb

I would like to join strings for file name and shell script so I can run the command line in kdb for ftp transfer.

But there are quotations in quotation marks. not sure how to add / in there.

This is the code I have:

```
host:"abc.com";
usr:"def";
path:"get /home/eddie/abc.csv /home/terry/";
cmd:" " sv ("/home/kdb/eddie/ftp.sh";host;usr;path);
system cmd;
```

So the path will not have quotation mark and will be running error. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: ok so i used 'Path'. any other way?

Comment: It's not very clear what you want the expected output to be, can you share that with us?

Answer (score 1):

You can escape quotes with `\` e.g. `"\"Matt\""` but I don't think that's your issue. It looks like you are attempting to use `get` in the system command. This is a kdb keyword and your OS will not recognise it. You should just be passing the location of the csv to your ftp script.

Edit:
You may also need `sh` in the system command.

```
cat test.sh
echo $1

system "test.sh hello"
sh: ./test.sh: Permission denied
'os

system "sh test.sh hello"
"hello"
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you simply want quotes within a string, it may just be as simple as using `.Q.s1` aka `-3!`, see https://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotq/#qs1-string-representation

```
q)" " sv ("/home/kdb/eddie/ftp.sh";host;usr;.Q.s1 path)
"/home/kdb/eddie/ftp.sh abc.com def \"get /home/eddie/abc.csv /home/terry/\""

q)" " sv ("/home/kdb/eddie/ftp.sh";host;usr;-3!path)
"/home/kdb/eddie/ftp.sh abc.com def \"get /home/eddie/abc.csv /home/terry/\""
```